# Is this possible to simplify this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have designed the following sql query to get the percentage of

```
100 -  ((reportedDate – Submission Date) / TotalNumOfVisits) * 100
```

Is there any way to simplify it? Like combine the two queries into one?

```
SELECT 
  q1.VisitMonth,q1.TotalVisit, ISNULL(q2.diff,0) AS DIFF
  ,100 - ISNULL( (CAST((q2.diff * 1.0 / q1.TotalVisit ) * 100 AS FLOAT)),0) PERC
FROM
(
  SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate) as VisitMonth, count(v.VisitID) as TotalVisit
  FROM Visits v
  INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
  WHERE a.ClientID IN (33,46)
    AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '31/12/2013'
  group by DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate)
) q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate) as MonthName,COUNT(*) as diff
  FROM Visits v
  INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
  WHERE a.ClientID IN (33,46)
    AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '31/12/2013'
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,v.ReportDate,v.SubmissionDate) > 2
  group by DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate)
) q2
ON q1.VisitMonth = q2.MonthName
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: There was a rule for C programs which I presume works for SQL, too: *Any C program can be reduced to one line which then contains at least one bug*. \*scnr\*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
 Select 
      VisitMonth,isnull(diff,0) as DIFF,
      100 - ISNULL( (CAST((diff * 1.0 / Nullif(TotalVisit,0) ) * 100 AS FLOAT)),0) PERC
 from 
 (
  SELECT 
       VisitMonth = Datename(month,visitDate) ,
       Diff =  Sum(case when DATEDIFF(DAY,v.ReportDate,v.SubmissionDate) > 2 then 1 
                   else 0 end) ,
       TotalVisit = Count(v.VisitID)
 FROM Visits v
 INNER JOIN Assignments a ON a.AssignmentID = v.AssignmentID
 WHERE a.ClientID IN (33,46)
 AND v.VisitDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '31/12/2013'
 group by DATENAME(MONTH,v.VisitDate)
)a
```

Comment: @parveen: thanks, it works great. Do you know if there is any performance difference b/w your query and the one i designed?

Comment: Sorry i think you have answered my question. Just out of interest, i have run the execution plan on both queries and your query plan cost 96% and mine 54%. Just wondering why your query cost 96% when it is clear and simple and has less nodes in execution plan. Sorry don't have any experience with execution plan.

Comment: @user1263981: `Where` clause will be executed before the computed column in `Select query`. In that case your query will first filter the data and then apply the logic where as my query will be applied for each and every row and check whether `DATEDIFF(DAY,v.ReportDate,v.SubmissionDate)' is `> 2`.Check this [article](http://www.sql.co.il/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf) by  Itzik Ben-Gan which shows the Logical order of processing by SQL Server. BTW not every `Simplified and readable` query will be `performant`